# How the De Finetti's Representation Theorem works in this case?

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, hierarchical-bayesian, definition, exchangeability

For the special case of infinite sequence of $\{0,1\}$ valued random variables the theorem is stated as
$$
Pr(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \int_0^1 p^{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)}[1-p]^{(n - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i)} dQ(p)\,.
$$
Where $Q(p)$ is a measure on probability for success $p \in [0,1]$ (that is $Q(\cdot)$ is a measure on space $[0,1]$)

So that any infinite exchangeable sequence of $\{0,1\}$ valued random variables can be though of as a realization of  a two step process

1. choose the value $p$ of the success probabilities according to $Q$.
2. condition on $p$ the $X_i$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli$(p)$.

Consider now a sequence such that $X_1 = X_2 = \cdots = X_n = 1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and $X_1 = X_2 = \cdots = X_n = 0$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. This is an exchangeable sequence of $\{0,1\}$ valued variables.

The "two step process" for this sequence works as the following: with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ pick $p=1$otherwise pick $p = 0$. This probability measure can be described as 
$$
Q(p) = \frac{1}{2}\delta_{1}(p) + \frac{1}{2}\delta_{0}(p)\,.
$$
If I plug this in the theorem I get

$$
\int_0^1 p^{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)}[1]^{(n - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i)} dQ(p)
= \frac{1}{2} \left( 0^{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)} [1-p]^{(n - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i)}\right) + \frac{1}{2} \left( 1^{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)} [0]^{(n - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i)}\right) = 0 \quad (?)\,.
$$

It's late, what am I doing wrong here?

Additionally, the other claim is that the value for $p$ should equal to the limiting long run proportion of successes, how does it works in this case?

Comment: A hint... $0^0 = 1$.  Look at the exponents in your final equation; they will either equal $n$ or $0$ if the probability is $1$ or $0$.

Comment: Oh I see, so in the only case where $\sum_i x_i = 0$ or $\sum_i x_i = n$ I get $0^0$, and that would recover the probability, thanks! I still however can not reconcile the claim that the long run proportion of successes i.e. $n^{-1}\sum x_i \to p$, should (somehow) also converge to the distribution $Q(p)$ (?)...

Comment: You won't get $Q$ back.  What happens is that $p$ is equal to $1$ or $0$, and the long run proportion of successes does equal $1$ or $0$ respectively.

Comment: @jbowman in general settings of this theorem, what does the empirical distribution function of $x_i$  (distribution that places mass $n^{-1}$ on $x_i$ converges to ?

Comment: In the Bernoulli case, the proportion of ones converges to  $p$ (which is a random variable)